# SCRIPT5: Access is denied. Fancybox iFrame. Same domain

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, dns

I am getting

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

jquery-1.4.2.min.js, line 127 character 344
```

in IE 7-9. I've found all kinds of questions on here with this problem, but I'm not crossing domains. All my URL's look fine. The script works fine in Firefox and Chrome. It's using jQuery, so I figure cross domain issues should be handled by the library. I'm at a loss right now and this seems pretty trivial. Any ideas? Please don't slam me with "same question already asked" stuff, because none of the other ones are helping me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it had to do with jQuery being old. Updated to the newest (1.7) and seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

And in the newest jQuery- 1.8.0 unfortunately problem is back.
I found also problem with positioning fancybox when it has YouTube video. Currently switched back to 1.7.2 as I don't have time to patch fancybox. If anyone else wrote patch I'll be glad for share it.

Comment: In jQuery v1.8.1 this bug is fixed again. I just spent 6 hours chasing a bug when, thanks to your answer, I realized there's a new version. I feel so stupid now.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling along this question, jQuery `1.10.1` also has this issue, but it has been fixed in `1.10.3`. [Here's the ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Also affects simple modal and probably a lot of other things. Adding this comment just so this shows up when googling for the same issue but with simple modal instead of fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jquery 1.10 and it throws the error everytime in an iFrame.  Outside the iFrame, jquery loads properly.